# Creation of Maze (labyrinth) with a character you control, and another which follows you (VBA)

Tags: excel, vba, maze

like the title suggest, I would like to create two fairly simple mazes (labyrinths) using VBA on Excel.

On the first I only have my character which I have to move from a point to another in order to escape.
I want the character to enter from the top left and to be able to exit from the bottom right.

On the second maze, I would like another maze, but this time, my character is closely followed by another one (which is supposed to be a monster which tries to eat my character).

If possible, I would like both characters to have an icon (like the pixel head of person for my character and the head of a monster for the character which follows in the second maze)

Thank you for your help and suggestions

I really am struggling to simple things on VBA, I just would like to make 2 simple mazes as stated.
If anyone could point me to which direction I should take it would be very simple.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read about [asking questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking).

Answer (score 0):

Start out using "Record Macro". Once you get a little used to the syntaxes, look up articles about avoiding the use of `select` and `selection`, and start looking into for loops. Use `'Option Explicit` at the first line, which makes it easier to avoid typos.

Comment: For me the issue really lies in the creation of the character.
I don't know what to use to make a character (a picture, insert a form?.. ) There's a lot of ressources which explain how to make a maze and its bordure from scratch, but I can't fin something which makes a character move through the maze

Comment: you could use emojis, like for example these ones:  

Comment: thank you, could you pleas explain to how I could easily make this emoji across my sheet ? i just would like to makee the character 1 cell up, 1 cell down, 1 cell right... etc I'm really a novice and I can't seem to see how to makee such simples things to make the emoji move

Comment: you can move it manually, i.e. if it's going to move right, then remove the emoji from its current position and add the emoji to the next cell (to the right, example: blank out cell e6 if the emoji was there, and put the emoji in f6). you need to decide how you're going to control the emoji (which input to use). the easiest may be to click on a cell and have the emoji move towards that cell.